# Transformation Matrices in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformation

I want to implement the forward kinematic of a robot with TensorFlow; mainly to gain automatic differentiation and to plug this module into larger network architectures.

In general I have a bunch of 4x4 transformation matrices, defined by the dh-parameters (*d*, *theta*, *a*, *alpha*) and the joint angle *q*:

```
[[           cos(theta+q),           -sin(theta+q),           0,             a],
 [sin(theta+q)*cos(alpha), cos(theta+q)*cos(alpha), -sin(alpha), -sin(alpha)*d],
 [sin(theta+q)*sin(alpha), cos(theta+q)*sin(alpha),  cos(alpha),  cos(alpha)*d],
 [                      0,                       0,           0,             1]])
```

My robot has 10 different joints, all connected sequentially.
I thought it would be smart to precompute sine and cosine.

```
q = tf.keras.layers.Input((10,))
sin_q = tf.sin(q)
cos_q = tf.cos(q)
```

Lets look at the transformation at the first joint with the specific set of dh-parameters (*d*=0.1055, *theta*=0, *a*=0, *alpha*=0):

```
m0 = [[cos(q0), -sin(q0), 0,       0],
      [sin(q0),  cos(q0), 0,       0],
            0,       0,   1, 0.10550],
            0,       0,   0,       1]]
```

My first problem is how to build something like this with TensorFlow?
In numpy I would initialize the matrix and fill in the nonzero values.

```
m_shape = tf.TensorShape((batch_size,4,4))
m0 = tf.zeros(m_shape)
m0[..., 0, 0] = cos_q[..., 0]
m0[..., 0, 1] = -sin_q[..., 0]
m0[..., 1, 0] = cos_q[..., 0]
m0[..., 1, 1] = sin_q[..., 0]
m0[..., 2, 3] = 0.10550
m0[..., 3, 3] = 1
Error -> 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

But Tensorflow doesn't allow assignment for tensors.
It seems that the way to go is via *tf.stack()*. I need to create a vector of ones of the same size as my not specified batch_size, stack and reshape.
(Note: In the general case there are less zero values)

```
e = tf.ones_like(q[..., 0]) 
m0 = tf.stack([cos_q[..., 0], -sin_q[..., 0], 0*e,       0*e,
               sin_q[..., 0],  cos_q[..., 0], 0*e,       0*e,
                         0*e,            0*e, 1*e, 0.10550*e,
                         0*e,            0*e, 0*e,       1*e], axis=-1)
m0 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((4, 4))(m0)
```

Is this correct or is there a smarter way to build such general transformations in TensorFlow?

As final result I am interested in the transformation at the end of the kinematic chain. I want to put in an array of different joint configurations (?, 10) and get the transformation at the end effector (?, 4, 4).

```
m_end = m0 @ m1 @ m2 @ ... @ m10
forward_net = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[q], outputs=[m_end]
result = forward_net.predict(np.random.random((100, 10)))
```

This works but its neither elegant nor fast. 
The speed is my bigger problem; the same implementation in numpy is 150x faster.

How can I improve the speed? I thought TensorFlow should excel at tasks like this.

Should I build it as *Model* and use *predict* to calculate the results; there is nothing to learn here, so I am not sure what to use.

Comment: The question is not very clear at the moment. What exactly you have (what tensors and shapes) and what do you want to get out of them? There seems to be little correspondence between the first two snippets (the first one involve two angles, `alpha` and `theta+q`, while the second one appears to try to build rotation matrices around the Z axis for certain angles. Do you want to go from `sin_q` and `cos_q` to a tensor containing rotation matrices in their last two dimensions (so the shape would be agumented with `(4, 4)`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build 4x4 rotation matrices from an angle, or from the sine and cosine of an angle, you can do it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_rotation(alpha, axis):
    return make_rotation_sincos(tf.math.sin(alpha), tf.math.cos(alpha), axis)

def make_rotation_sincos(sin, cos, axis):
    axis = axis.strip().lower()
    zeros = tf.zeros_like(sin)
    ones = tf.ones_like(sin)
    if axis == 'x':
        rot = tf.stack([
            tf.stack([ ones, zeros, zeros], -1),
            tf.stack([zeros,   cos,  -sin], -1),
            tf.stack([zeros,   sin,   cos], -1),
        ], -2)
    elif axis == 'y':
        rot = tf.stack([
            tf.stack([  cos, zeros,   sin], -1),
            tf.stack([zeros,  ones, zeros], -1),
            tf.stack([ -sin, zeros,   cos], -1),
        ], -2)
    elif axis == 'z':
        rot = tf.stack([
            tf.stack([  cos,  -sin, zeros], -1),
            tf.stack([  sin,   cos, zeros], -1),
            tf.stack([zeros, zeros,  ones], -1),
        ], -2)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid axis {!r}.'.format(axis))
    last_row = tf.expand_dims(tf.stack([zeros, zeros, zeros], -1), -2)
    last_col = tf.expand_dims(tf.stack([zeros, zeros, zeros, ones], -1), -1)
    return tf.concat([tf.concat([rot, last_row], -2), last_col], -1)
```

---

About computing the forward kinematic chain, you can do that with [`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan). For example, assuming the initial shape `(?, 10)`:

```
# Make rotation matrices
rots = make_rotation(...)
rots_t = tf.transpose(rots, (1, 0, 2, 3))
out = tf.scan(tf.matmul, rots_t)[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you. This definitely looks cleaner, but in my case the transformations are not only along the coordinate axes and in addition I have the translation.
Is layered stacking faster than one stack + reshape?

Comment: @scleronomic No, one stack + reshape should actually be at least as fast if that is a concern (in principle faster, although TF might optimize the operation to something not so different). I tried to make it clearer here, but that works too.

Comment: @scleronomic I just realised your question was also about computing the forward IK chain, I have added how you may do that with `tf.scan`.